# Storing large image files in database vs system files

Tags: datafile, filestream, filetable

I need to store many large photos that will be uploaded daily in my application and retrieve those with id. There is no need to any special queries.
What is the best approach for storing this files consider to time that number of the images pass a million and side of images exceed the server disk size. What is the most manageable solution?

1. Using SQL FileStream or FileTable and storing files in separate database.
2. Using file system and saving images as files.
3. Using a FTP server.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? For SQL Server read this: http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525

Comment: SQL server. Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name that was really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Second option is much better that first for sure as for first option, there will be conversion of images to binary while saving and decoding the same while retiriving which is overhead.

So i would suggest store location of file in database and store images in file system.

Comment: Storing images in the filesystem is not always faster: http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525